I want to make a blog for my website on GitHub Pages with Jekyll?
I have been trying to put together a blog via Jekyll on my website for a while. I know how to setup jekyll and serve it, but it seems that GitHub Pages only allows to serve one repo (server) to the public via a custom domain.
How can I serve my main website AND the blog with Jekyll (or I would be greatful if you suggested a better idea) as a section on my website?

On the GitHub pages, you can only serve one repo as your root website. However, you can also serve other repos as subfolders to your main website.
For example, the main website is example.github.io, and the repo is example.github.io. This repo will be served in URL https:\\example.github.io\.
Now you want a separate repo for your blog, so you can create a repo named blog and enable Jekyll in that repo and this repo will be served on https:\\example.github.io\blog\

Note: Make sure that your main repo does not have a subfolder named blog that may cause issues.

